# Apache reverse proxy issue with otree/django

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy, django-channels, otree

I am trying to set up apache with SSL as a reverse proxy for an oTree application. oTree is a framework for social science experiment that is build on django and also uses django channels. The reverse proxy generally works but I am having issues with websockets.

My apache config is

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ServerName myurl.net
ProxyRequests Off
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) wss://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P,L]

ServerName myurl.net
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myurl.net/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I get the following error in apache

```
[Wed Jan 06 15:42:51.137016 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 5573:tid 140468195309312] [client myip] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /no_op/
[Wed Jan 06 15:42:59.029500 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 5574:tid 140468096587520] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client myip] AH01084: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:8000 (127.0.0.1)
```

In my browser I get the following error.

```
(index):94 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myurl.net/create_demo_session/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing?

EDIT: For reference, the following NGINX configuration works:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate "mycertificate";
    ssl_certificate_key "mycertificate";
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run **oTree** on a subdomain of your host so that you can share port 80 with other sites hosted on the same machine, you can try the below configuration. The below example assumes oTree server is running on port 8000. For HTTPS, change 80 to 443 ws prefix to **wss:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName otree.domain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and i still get the same error  " WebSocket connection to 'wss://myurl.net/create_demo_session/' failed:"  However, i have found a ngix configuration that works for me, which I am using now.

Comment: can u share the ngnix configuration that you are using for my reference

Comment: I edited the original post to include the nginx configurarion